# ByteArray show not hexadecimal digits Python

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I'm working with an array of bytes extracted from an UDP packet in Python.

The data it's represented like this:

```
data = [0x00,0x01,0x23,0x84,0xa6]
```

And when I use `bytearray(data)` and prints its content the prompt shows me a not hexadecimal digit like `x01#` or with other data contents the `#` digit its replace by a `\n` digit. I don't really know why this happens.

**The complete code example**

```
data = [0x00,0x01,0x23,0x84,0xa6]

data1 = bytearray(data)

print(data)
print(data1)
```

**And the print shows**

```
[0, 1, 35, 132, 166]
bytearray(b'\x00\x01#\x84\xa6')
```

Using `bytes(data)` the problem is the same.

Comment: If you're asking "how do I get my bytearray to display itself like "00012384a6"?", take a look at its `hex()` method. If that's not what you're asking, please describe exactly what output you'd like to see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `bytearray` is represented as a string.  When a string is represented for human eyes the characters are displayed according to the current encoding (`ASCII`, `utf-8`, etc.).  In your current encoding, the character with the value `0x23` is a hash-symbol (`#`).  Only for the bytes which do not have a character representation (`0x00`, etc.) the hex representation is displayed (e.g. `\x00`).

So what you see is absolutely correct because you asked (maybe without knowing) for a string representation of your byte array.

If you want to see a hex value for each byte, use `data1.hex()`.  This will create a hex representation for each byte and concatenate all of these.  The result will be a string containing only hex digits (`0-9` and `a-f`).  This is only useful for printing, in most cases it is not useful for further processing.

In Python3, consider using `bytes([0x00, 0x01, ...])` instead.  That will produce a `bytes` object which is more native to the language (e.g. many functions like `write()`, `send()`, etc. will accept it as input).  It also has a `hex()` method as described above.